# Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type StreamingBlobTypes error for javascript aws-sdk/client-s3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When using Buffer in a aws s3 javascript client PutObjectRequest I get at build time:

```
Type 'Buffer' is not assignable to type 'StreamingBlobTypes | undefined'.
```

or if using a string

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'StreamingBlobTypes | undefined'.
```

How do I convert Buffer to StreamingBlobTypes ?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions was to convert Buffer to Readable stream for example:

```
import { Readable } from "stream";

  saveCreativeImage(name: string, image: Buffer): Promise<string> {
    const options: PutObjectRequest = {
      ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control',
      Bucket: EnvConfig.S3_CREATIVES_BUCKET_NAME,
      Key: name,
      Body:  Readable.from(image),
      ContentType: 'image/png',
      ContentLength: image.length
    };
```

Note you need to include the ContentLength header otherwise you will see in your logs:

```
A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
```

and

```
Are you using a Stream of unknown length as the Body of a PutObject request? Consider using Upload instead from @aws-sdk/lib-storage.
```

If you are using a string, you can convert it to Buffer and then use the above solution like:

```
const stringBuffer: Buffer = Buffer.from(mystring);
```

The StreamingBlobTypes  type is from
https://github.com/awslabs/smithy-typescript